# remove request file from laravel request

Tags: laravel

When I want upload file with form in laravel, I cant remove **file value** from request.

This is my full code

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $string_name = str_random(12);
            $image = $request->file('image')->move(getcwd().'/image/original',$string_name.'.'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $request->request->remove('image');
        }
        if($request->hasFile('thumbnail')){
            $string_name = str_random(12);
            $thumbnail = $request->file('thumbnail')->move(getcwd().'/image/thumbnail',$string_name.'.'.$request->file('thumbnail')->getClientOriginalExtension());
        }

        Portfolio::create($request->all());
```

but `image` or `thumbnail` file do not remove from `$request`. This means this line of code not working :

```
$request->request->remove('image');
```

I've tried many ways but the `file` does not get removed from the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of removing the `image` from your `$request` before saving, you can explicitly mention what you would like to save to your model by using the `->only([])` method on `$request`.

```
Portfolio::create($request->only(['title', ...]));
```

This will allow you to specify exactly what you would like saved from the `$request` data.

You can do the reverse and use the `->except()` method to remove the `image` too:

```
Portfolio::create($request->except('image'));
```

Comment: Also, to be safe, I would `validate` the data before saving. If using laravel 5.7, you are able to use the `$this->validate()` method to return only data which has been checked.

Comment: thanks . but maybe the table has many column . and maybe user did not selected any file ?

Comment: In your `if()` statement, you have already caught if the user has uploaded an `image`.

Comment: The other way would be to store `$request->all()` into a variable (e.g. `$data`) and then `isset($data['image'])` to remove image from the array.

Comment: if I convert object to array can I use ->move and other file request method?

Comment: Converting to an `array` should happen **after** using `->move()`. After that is done, you can do anything with the data as you are only saving to the model. The answer isn't to replace the first part of your code.

Comment: if I have two file like image and thumbnail if first section if I convert object to array and replace image to $request[image] in second file example thumbnail i cant use ->move and other staff . right?

Comment: @user3243573 Please use updated answer (`expect()` method). Do not convert to array.

Answer (score 0):

use this to remove the file

```
$request->offsetUnset('input_file_name');
```

or

```
$request->except('filename');
```